# Updating a SQL server from a remote .dbf file

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008, synchronization

I currently have two servers. One is a server with .dbf files that get updated very frequently, and the other is a server with SQL Server workgroup edition on it.

Problem: I need to update the SQL Server tables from these remote .dbf files, how is it done? I need these files to be pulled automatically from the server every X amount of hours.

Research thus far:

I believe I understand how to update tables having the .dbf file on the same server as the SQL Server database, you would use the DTS management studio provided with SQL Server. I don't believe this solution would work trying to pull these .dbf files remotely. I have looked into a Linked Server, but don't understand what that really is. These .dbf files come from a visual foxpro server. As far as i know visual foxpro has no interface like SQL? If anyone has any advice in order to point me into the right direction, this would be much appreciated. I can usually find the answers, but feel pretty helpless on this one... Thanks in advance for any effort put into this problem.

Comment: Are the servers networked together, and if so, can you connect to the .dbf file over the network?

Comment: these servers are not networked together, one is a go daddy dedicated server, the other is a dedicated server somewhere else

Answer (score 3):

A linked server is basically just a pointer that lets the code within your database interact with external data sources as if they were also within your database/instance. There are some examples here for creating linked servers to FoxPro DBFs:

http://fox.wikis.com/wc.dll?Wiki~VisualFoxProDataFromSQLServer

So for example if you had a linked server to a FoxPro database called MyFoxProDB you could run a query within SQL Server like this:

```
UPDATE t
    SET t.foo = x.bar
    FROM dbo.LocalTable AS t
    INNER JOIN MyFoxProDB...TableName AS x
    ON t.key = x.key;
```

You could also consider using `OPENROWSET` as described in this question:

[Import DBF files into Sql Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/883917/import-dbf-files-into-sql-server)

(But personally I think the linked server will be a lot more flexible.)

Comment: Thank you for the great fast post. I think this is becoming more clear to me with your great example, but i think i am still confused on the actual physical connection of the servers. . . like shouldnt there be a connection string or something of that nature? i dont really understand how to connect to that server. Do i need to remove all remote logins to the VFP database so it can make the link happen?

Comment: The "connection string" is part of the linked server setup - you only need to establish that once, then SQL Server negotiates it from then on. I'll admit I have literally zero experience with FoxPro, so I'm not fully aware of the security model there, or whether you're asking about concurrency...

Comment: @Mootz - FoxPro is a file database and the *physical connection* to the server is a file share where you actually use the .dbf files directly. There no difference if you use a linked server or SSIS, you have to access the files through a share.