# Import FoxPro database into SQL Server

Tags: sql, database, import, sql-server-express, foxpro

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to import a DBF file in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52822/how-to-import-a-dbf-file-in-sql-server)

Can a Foxpro database (abc.dbf) be imported into SQL Server?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to import a DBF file in SQL Server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/52822/how-to-import-a-dbf-file-in-sql-server) - see the answer here - it's really quite simple, once you know how to do it